# New Manager at a New Company and feeling Anxious?

Tags: management, human-resources, leadership, anxiety

I started a new job yesterday with a new company as a manager. I've been managing for few years at different departments but it has all been under the same company. Now, I'm totally at a new company (a competitor of my previous company), I don't know how to explain my feelings maybe I'm feeling a bit anxious? I met with my direct reports and did a one-on-one with them to get to know each other better, all went well. I can see a lot of potentials and areas of opportunity. I'm not trying to lay down rules from day one or bring change immediately. I'm trying to gain their trust and respect. I still need to get used to their system even though I've been in this industry for several years now. Do you think this "anxious" feeling is coming because I don't know anyone in the company yet? Have you ever been through this? I've taken over new teams before but it has been under the same company, I don't think I've felt like this before. I feel very confident that I can bring great results here but I just don't know why I might be feeling like this.

Have you experienced this when you join a totally new company without knowing anyone? Do you agree with me at first building rapport with my team before I set expectations? When do you think I should move into the sales goal piece? I was thinking once I'm done with training so I can understand the system before I set expectations so I can lead by example? Once again I've only been here for two days and I feel like there are so many missed opportunities but I don't want to come off aggressive from the beginning when I start suggesting things. What other advice do you have for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations on your new job! This "anxiety" is only normal in the start phase. It will fade away as the job gets to be a routine (in a good way meant) and you get familiar with the environment and people. Just give it some time. As for your other concerns, you seem to have a good plan! Other advices: just listen to people, they will show you what they need and expect from you. Be patient and it will get great!

Answer (score 2):

I think I read somewhere, that as a new manager you will have 100 days to arrive, settle, shake hands, do the 1:1s and analyze your environment. Stakeholders, peers, reports, targets, structure and processes. After 100 days it is expected that you are clearly present/visible as the head of that team/department/branch etc.. and your reports report to you as their new manager.

About that anxious feeling; I can speak from my experiences as a consultant entering different companies and cultures monthly or weekly: Every company is different, every team is different. Find your place and try to blend in in the company culture and the team culture. Once you are respected, address your opinions without encroaching others.

Maybe one of the hardest things: You come with a lot of ideas and know how to succeed in the industry. However be careful, address it diplomatically and gently. Some people will not accept your ideas (as they do not trust you yet) and some people have a hardship with change in general.